# Implement a list of constant objects

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a basic class `Object`, which has some `int`s and `std::string`s (so not really big).

Now, I need some sort of list of `Object`s that wouldn't change, but I should still be able to search it (using a function for example). This "list" is created only at compile time and it will have approx. 60 objects. I currently have 2 solutions:

1. Create a class `Objects` that has a `std::vector<Object>` and which gets initialized in the constructor (along with the search functions).
2. Create a namespace which contains the `Objects` as constants and a `std::vector<Object>` for search (and the like) functions (which will be defined in the namespace).

One disadvantage of `1` is that it has to create the 60+ objects every time I need to access them. `2` is probably ok, but one must not forget to put a new object to the `std::vector` as well as in the top "list".

`1` might be implemented like this:

```
class Objects
{
public:
    Objects()
    {
        list.push_back(Object{ 0 });
        list.push_back(Object{ 1 });
    };

    bool hasValue(int value)
    {
        for (auto& obj: list)
        {
            if (obj.getValue() == value)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Object> list;
};
```

`2` like so:

```
namespace Objects
{
    const Object obj1{ 0 };
    const Object obj2{ 1 };

    const std::vector<Object> list{ obj1, obj2 };

    bool hasValue(int value)
    {
        for (auto& obj: list)
        {
            if (obj.getValue() == value)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Which way would be the best in terms of coding practice and/or usability/maintainability? Maybe there is another way that I haven't thought of?

Comment: It depends. The characteristics of Object, how big it it, how many there will be, whether the list needs to be built at runtime or whether you can compute it at compile time. Can you elaborate? maybe post a small program to demonstrate the use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 Objects that never change and need to always be available?

Sounds like a job for a function that returns a reference to a static array. All standard algorithms (in this case `find_if`) work with a `std::array`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct Object
{
    Object(int i) : _i(i) {};

    int _i;
};

const std::array<Object, 20>& objects()
{
    static std::array<Object, 20> os = {
        Object(1),
        Object(2),
        Object(3),
        Object(4),
        Object(5),
        Object(6),
        Object(7),
        Object(8),
        Object(9),
        Object(10),
        Object(11),
        Object(12),
        Object(13),
        Object(14),
        Object(15),
        Object(16),
        Object(17),
        Object(18),
        Object(19),
        Object(20)
    };
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto const& os = objects();
    auto i_ten = std::find_if(std::begin(os), 
                              std::end(os), 
                              [](auto const& o) { 
                                  return o._i == 10; });

    cout << i_ten->_i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```